# Ajax request not directing to URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been working with other ajax requests in my document and I haven't had any issue. I want to find the coordinates of a user as they load the document, then pass this data onto other methods to calculate distances.

I've created a javascript document which is called on the `index.php` loading. This is the function:

```
function getCurrentLocation(username) {
var latitude = "";
var longitude = "";

if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };

  latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  console.log(latitude);
  console.log(longitude);

  sendCoords(latitude, longitude, username);

});
}

}

function sendCoords(lat, long, username){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "includes/handlers/ajax_update_loc.php",
data: "lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long + "&username=" + username,

success: function() {
  console.log("UPDATE LOCATION");

}
});
}
```

I've added a series of logs to keep track of the logic and it works in order as expected. The log in the the url file, `ajax_update_loc.php` is not called.

This is the ajax_update_loc.php` file:

```
<?php

include("../../config/config.php");
include("../classes/User.php");

$currentLoc = new User($con, $_REQUEST['username']);
$currentLoc->updateLocation($_REQUEST);

?>

<script>

console.log("OP")
</script>

<?php

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers SO!

Comment: Where do you define `long`? If you add `console.log("lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long + "&username=" + username)`, is the correct data printed to the console?

Comment: @TheCodesee: It's the second formal parameter to the `sendCoords` function.

Comment: _"The log in the the url file, ajax_update_loc.php is not called."_ - just because you make a _request_ for something doesn't automatically mean it will get "executed". You have only requested this document so far, but not done anything with it. So go research what you need to do with the _result_ of your AJAX request, if you want HTML code inside it to be shown, and JS code inside of it to be executed.

Comment: I tried your code and it works on my machine, the PHP script gets the location info. Have you checked the browser console network tab to see if the AJAX request is sent? If it's sent check the PHP error log, maybe the code is generating an error and aborting the execution of the script.

Comment: to get the logs from `ajax_update_loc.php` file change your ajax `success` code to `success: function(response) {
  console.log(response);

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getCurrentLocation(username) {
var latitude = "";
var longitude = "";

if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };

 var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  console.log(latitude);
  console.log(longitude);

  

});
}

}

function sendCoords(){

$.post("includes/handlers/ajax_update_loc.php",{latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude, username:username},function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      
   });

</script>
```

here you can send parameters with ajax in your update file then you can play with them to update the location

Comment: is it worKing ?